# Is it safe for property to update its elements every time its called?

Tags: c#, properties

I have a property, `IList <IMyPlayer> Players {}`, which syncs with the game server every time it is summoned. I need to know if it will update every increment when made limiting count in a for loop. The reason why is I'm worried a player may leave the game during this loop.

*edit* this is a single thread application.

```
public static IList <IMyPlayer> Players
{
    get
    {
        playersField.Clear(); //GetPlayers() just adds without overwriting so list must be cleared every time.

        if (Debugging == false)
        {
            MyAPIGateway.Multiplayer.Players.GetPlayers (playersField); //everytime the project needs to see all players, this will update. Little heavier on performance but its polymorphic. 
        }    
        return playersField.AsReadOnly();
    }
} 

for (int i = 0; i < AttendanceManager.Players.Count; i++)
{
    if (AttendanceManager.Players[i].SteamUserId == MyAPIGateway.Multiplayer.MyId)
    {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are working with multiple threads a `lock` around the `Players` list would prevent that

Comment: Hi this is a single thread application.

Comment: @Dr.Fre, and Samuel: in the last loop, even if the Players.Count is cached, then this line: `AttendanceManager.Players[i].SteamUserId` will invoke the getter at every loop iteration, and it will invoke Clear, GetPlayers and AsReadOnly for each iteration. That's a very bad idea. Usually.

Comment: Excellent thats what i needed to know! :]

Comment: Maybe just use `foreach(var player in AttendanceManager.Players)`..

Comment: Use LINQ instead :)
`foreach(var player in AttendanceManager.Players.Where(p => p.SteamUserId == MyAPIGateway.Multiplayer.MyId))`

Comment: @MiklósTóth - Is there a reason you recommend LINQ vs a traditional `for` loop?

Comment: any downvoters please tell me how can I improve this question for you?

Comment: @Tim Mainly a matter of taste. It is cleaner, simpler. And actually *it drives your way of thinking*. If you start thinking in a linq way, it will save you from basic bad practices like the one in this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see several potential problems with your approach:

- You add items while you are looping over it, but only loop until the *original* count is reached. So any added items are not accessed by the `for` loop
- Your getter is doing more than a "normal" getter, which could mean performance problems if clients are not aware of that
- using `foreach` would only call the getter once, which would behave differently that your `for` loop.

If you want to do this, I would instead make it a `GetPlayers()` function which makes it clearer that you are *creating* something as part of the method, and not just getting the current value of a property.  If a client wants to reload the list each time they are stil lfree to do so, but it would be more obvious looking at the code.

For example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < AttendanceManager.GetPlayers().Count; i++)
{
    if (AttendanceManager.GetPlayers()[i].SteamUserId == MyAPIGateway.Multiplayer.MyId)
```

look much more dodgy than a standard property getter.

Answer (score 1):

I would most certainly not do this.

Every time you use your property it is going to call an API. That is going to be terrible for performance. Also it could be quite easy for your property to be called multiple times, even if you don't think it will be. One example I can think of is serialization, or if you are using this as an argument to say an MVC or Web API controller method.

This is what is commonly referred to as a side-effect, which is something you want to avoid in a getter at all costs.